# React property is an empty object instead of intended array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I'm trying to implement a `GroupedList` from the Office UI Fabirc control library and I'm not too far off from the demo code [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/groupedlist).  For some reason, when passing the items array into the function component I have built through the props (TimeDisplay), I'm losing the list.  I get an empty Javascript object for the `itemsArray` parameter instead of the dummy array that was set up in the calling "Home" compoment.  Why don't I get my little array?  I'm guessing this is just me missing something about the way React works, but I would appreciate any insight.

**Relevant Code**

Home.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TimeSubmitter } from './TimeSubmitter'
import { TimeDisplay, TimeEntry } from './TimeDisplay'

type HomeProps = {

}

export class Home extends Component<HomeProps> {
  static displayName = Home.name;
  private items: TimeEntry[] = new Array<TimeEntry>();

  constructor(props: HomeProps){
    super(props);
    this.items.push(
      {
        client: "Apple",
        hours: 1,
        timeCode: "MD",
        loggedDate: new Date()
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TimeDisplay title="Time Logged this Period" items={this.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

TimeDisplay.tsx

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react'; 
import { GroupedList, IGroup } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/GroupedList';
import { IColumn, DetailsRow } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DetailsList';
import { FocusZone } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/FocusZone';
import { Selection, SelectionMode, SelectionZone } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Selection';

type TimeDisplayProps = {
    title: string,
    items: TimeEntry[]
  }
export type TimeEntry = {
    client: string,
    hours: number,
    timeCode: string,
    loggedDate: Date
}

const buildGroups = (items: Array<TimeEntry>) => {
    let groups = new Array<IGroup>();
    let hashSet = new Set<string>();
    for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        const element = items[index];
        if(!hashSet.has(element.client)){
            groups.push({
                key: element.client,
                name: element.client,
                startIndex: 0,
                count: 10
            });
            hashSet.add(element.client);
        }
      }
      return groups;
    }

const buildColumns = (item: TimeEntry[]) => {
    return (Object.keys(item)
      .map(
        (key: string): IColumn => ({
          key: key,
          name: key,
          fieldName: key,
          minWidth: 300
        })
      ));
}

export const TimeDisplay: FunctionComponent<TimeDisplayProps> = (title, itemsArray) =>{
    const [items, setItems] = useState(itemsArray);
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState(new Selection());
    const [groups, setGroups] = useState(buildGroups(itemsArray));
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(buildColumns(itemsArray[0]));

    const onRenderCell = (nestingDepth?: number | undefined, item?: any, index?: number | undefined) => {
        if(nestingDepth != undefined && index != undefined){
            return (
                <DetailsRow
                  columns={columns}
                  groupNestingDepth={nestingDepth}
                  item={item}
                  itemIndex={index | 0}
                  selection={selection}
                  selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
                  compact={false}
                />);
        }
    }

    return (        
    <FocusZone>
        <SelectionZone selection={selection} selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}>
          <GroupedList
            items={items}
            onRenderCell={onRenderCell}
            selection={selection}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.single}
            groups={groups}
          />
        </SelectionZone>
      </FocusZone>);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.items` is just a property on your Home component. Changing it won't cause a re-render either of Home or the TimeDisplay component you're passing it to. You also need to destructure your props received in TimeDisplay.

So firstly, you should use state; in your constructor you could write something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TimeSubmitter } from './TimeSubmitter';
import { TimeDisplay, TimeEntry } from './TimeDisplay';

type HomeProps = {};

export class Home extends Component<HomeProps> {
  static displayName = Home.name;
  private items: TimeEntry[] = new Array<TimeEntry>();

  constructor(props: HomeProps) {
    super(props);

    // set initial state with your object inside the items array
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          client: 'Apple',
          hours: 1,
          timeCode: 'MD',
          loggedDate: new Date()
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    // change this.items to this.state.items
    return (
      <div>
        <TimeDisplay title='Time Logged this Period' items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then in TimeDisplay you should write `({title, itemsArray})` instead of `(title, itemsArray)`, as props are passed as a single object.

I also noticed some other things in your code you might want to address:

`HomeProps`, `TimeDisplayProps` and `TimeEntry` should all be `interface`s, not types. Just change type to interface and remove the equals sign.

Also, a neater way to write this...

```
for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        const element = items[index];
        if(!hashSet.has(element.client)){
            groups.push({
                key: element.client,
                name: element.client,
                startIndex: 0,
                count: 10
            });
            hashSet.add(element.client);
        }
      }
      return groups;
    }
```

Would be to use the forEach method on your array, like...

```
items.forEach(element => {
  if (!hashSet.has(element.client)) {
    groups.push({
      key: element.client,
      name: element.client,
      startIndex: 0,
      count: 10
    });
    hashSet.add(element.client);
  }

  return groups;
});
```

Hope this all makes sense!

Comment: That does make sense, and I'm not shocked it was something dumb.  Agree on the forEach too.  I had it that way initially but I keep getting a complaint that "items.forEach is not a function" so I changed it to a for loop.  Not sure why it is doing that eiter.

Comment: I would guess in the original code `items` wasn't initialising as an array (for reasons outlined in the answer), so when it looked for the forEach method it wouldn't be able to find it.

Comment: Ha, that does make sense.  I'll definitely put the forEach back then!  I'll test this tonight and accept your answer since you got here first. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the destructuring in your definition of the functional component. So functional components get a `props` argument as the first parameter, which contains ALL the props as object keys. If you want to destructure them directly in the definition, then you need the curly braces. Right now `itemsArray` in your functional component is referring to the *second* argument a functional component gets, which is a reference forwarded using `React.forwardRef(...)`. [See here for more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components).

So, define your functional component with curly braces around prop keys, like this:

```
export const TimeDisplay: FunctionComponent<TimeDisplayProps> = ({title, itemsArray}) =>{
...
```

Comment: You are right.  I guess I'm still not used to the functional component syntax.